# Scapy: packet.time vs Timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, scapy

What is the relationship between the [packet arrival time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615892/scapy-get-packets-arrivals-time) you get using packet.time

```
1628612981.267997
```

(which seem to have sub-second accuracy) and the timestamp found in packet['TCP'].options?

```
Timestamp: ('Timestamp', (126599704, 1805779421))
```

From what I understand, the [timestamp tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58256895/945347) is Val (the actual timestamp) and Ecr (echo reply). Is packet.time a scapy-specific thing? Is the timestamp only accurate to the second?

Answer (score 1):

The packet arrival time is the time of capture of the packet.
when it arrived at the interface you used to capture.

The TCP.option's time is a time that the sender of the packet inserted.
You could consider that time as the sending time of the packet.

So the relation is:
arival_time = time_in_network + tcp.option.timestamp